# Что такое сложные элементы WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Попросили сделать презентацию на тему "Использования сложных элементов WPF". Никак не могу понять что именно такое сложные элементы.

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, что такое простые.

Comment: С простыми я уже разобрался, но нужно именно расказать про сложные

Comment: Официально элементы не делятся на простые и сложные, есть просто элементы. Поэтому сложность понятие субъективное. Кому-то сложно собирать составные элементы, а кому-то сложно шаблонами думать и стилями. Тут уже надо уточнять у того, кто поставил задачу, что такое "сложные элементы".

Comment: Ну вот сложные - это те, которые не простые. :)

Comment: Можешь дать несколько примеров элементов которые сложные как на тебя.

Comment: Небось имеется в виду `UserControl`?